# ASP.NET MVC Function Of DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I create custom controller factory what in this situations this row of code means

**DependencyResolver.Current.GetService** ?

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            Type targetType = null;

            switch (controllerName)
            {
                case "Product":
                    targetType = typeof(ProductController);
                    break;
                case "Customer":
                    targetType = typeof(CustomerController);
                    break;
                default:
                    requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Product";
                    targetType = typeof(ProductController);
                    break;
            }

            return targetType == null ? null :
            (IController)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(targetType); // what this means here ?
        }
```

Comment: That's service location.

Comment: Are you reading Adam Freeman?

Comment: Yes I am reading Freeman. Did you read the same book ?

Answer (score 1):

That line means that programmers wants current dependency resolver to resolve a service of a specified type.

If your resolver is set right, it will return an instance of the type you specified.

You can also use the generic version to avoid cast.

Also I would suggest not to use magic strings and instead use enums or other strong values.

Answer (score 1):

This means that current dependency resolver should resolve dependence of targetType. Bassically it's implementation of [Service Locator design pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ServiceLocator.aspx).

To set dependency resolver you should use `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(myResolver)` in `Application_Start`